# Smooth requestAnimationFrame using Jquery.animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am trying to repeatedly move a div to the right using `requestAnimationFrame` and Jquery's `animate()`. However, my div seems to stutter instead of continuously move. How come it keeps starting and stopping?

[Here is a JSfiddle of my implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/0zLqw9op/)

If you want to just see my code here is the html:

```
<body>
  <div id="back">
    <div id="myDiv">
    </div> 
  </div>
</body>
```

The css:

```
#myDiv {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

#back {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

And the javascript:

```
  function updateFrame(){
      $("#myDiv").animate({left: '+=25px'}, function(){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateFrame);
      });
    }


  updateFrame();
```

Comment: why would you want to combine `.animate()` with `rAF`? was there a problem using just the `.animate()` method?

Comment: What if I want to animate more than just that div on the animation frame?

Comment: hmm, that still doesn't really put a good case for the combination in my view. `$('#myDIV')` currently returns you one element. you could pass a class selector (or what not) instead and have multiple elements animating.

Comment: But say I want to animate one thing a certain way and another a different way

Comment: I could be wrong but I think your understanding of `.animate()` method and `rAF` is a little off. Don't get me wrong but calling `.animate()` method almost `60` times a second thanks to `rAF` shouldn't be the way. You could instead use `.css()` method in place of `.animate()` and still achieve a similar result: **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/ctavexyz/)**.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I used for my first version of my program but I thought `animate` was more efficient. I was using a `setInterval` to change the `css` every fraction of a second and for this implementation I moved to `rAF` and using `animate`, but I guess I'll just use `rAF` and change `css` if you say thats better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106976/discussion-between-tahir-ahmed-and-markscode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
  function updateFrame(){
      $("#myDiv").animate({left: '+=1px'}, 10, function(){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updateFrame);
      });
    }


  updateFrame();
```

use `left: 1px` instead of `25px` then use animate `speed`.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zLqw9op/1/)**